# Deleting correct in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a short question with a many-to-many relationship.
Here are my tables:

```
+---------+----------------+
| film_id | title          | 
+---------+----------------+
|       1 | Apocalypse Now |
+---------+----------------+


+-------------+----------------------+
| category_id | name                 | 
+-------------+----------------------+
|           1 | cool category        |
+-------------+----------------------+
|           2 | not so cool category |
+-------------+----------------------+

+---------+-------------+
| film_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           1 |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           2 |
+---------+-------------+
```

As you can see there are FKs from the `film`- and `category`-table in the `film_category`-table.

**What I want**: If one wants to delete a `category`, then ALL entries in the `film_category` where the `category_id` occurs should be deleted, too. BUT not the related `film`s! In addition to that: This should work while deleting a `film` vice versa! (That's exactly my problem here)

**My Question**: Can I solve the issue with a FK-definition only or do I have to delete all entries in the `film_category`-table manually before deleting a `film` or  `category`?

Comment: You can achieve this with a normal `ON DELETE CASCADE` referential triggered action on the foreign key.

Comment: When I do that and then deleting a `category`, the related `film` is also deleted.

Comment: Can you post your table and foreign key definitions, [in the sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f8ae0/1) I have done, when a category is deleted it only deletes the rows in film_category with that category_id, and leaves the film table untouched.

Comment: My `film_category`-table has a composite PK with `film_id`+`category_id`. That's the only difference I see :/

Comment: This shouldn't make any difference. [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a00f8/1).

Comment: Okay I think u showed me how it should work. I can't show you my `CREATE`s now, because I am not at work right now. Also the `CREATE`s and FKs are generated from MySQL Workbench. So when I add a many-to-many relationship it generates the FKs with `NO ACTION` and I added `CASCADE`, but then the error I described pops. I don't know right now, but maybe Workbench added some freaky definitions?

Comment: For some reason it works now. I don't know why or how but I am sure 1 or 2 `film`s where deleted yesterday while I deleted a `category`... Sorry about that and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables should look something like the following. A delete in the film table should delete the rows where the film category has the same id, and vice versa with the film table.

```
CREATE TABLE `film` (
  `film_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`film_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `film_category` (
 `film_category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `film_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`film_category_id`),
 KEY `film_id` (`film_id`),
 KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `film_category_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`category_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `film_category_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`film_id`) REFERENCES `film` (`film_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You should also be able to use the following for film_category:

```
CREATE TABLE `film_category` (
  `film_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`film_id`,`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `film_category_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`film_id`) REFERENCES `film` (`film_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `film_category_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`category_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: The difference to my table is that your `film_category` has its own ID and only this is the PK. My `film_category` has no own ID and it gots a composite PK with `film_id`+`category_id`. So do you think thats the problem it deletes also the related `film` when I delete a `category`?

Comment: I added the film_category table example with the composite primary key above. If you delete category.category_id 1, then it should only remove row 1,1 but leave 1,2 in the film_category table.